# Выпадающее меню с под меню

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('.active').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  //закрыть все открытие элементы списка
  $('.slide_menu').slideUp();
  //открыть только нужный список 
  $(this).parent().find('.slide_menu').slideToggle();
  // но получается что при закрытии нужного элемента в списке, он 
  закрывается и сразу открывается 
});
```

Создал *вертикальный аккордеон* так что отрытии второго вертикального элемента в списке, закрывается предыдущий это хорошо, но плохо что при закрытии элемента в списке кликом на активный элемент, этот элемент сначала закрывается а потом опять **открывается!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.active').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  const target = $(this).parent().find('.slide_menu');

  // прежде, чем закрыть все открытие элементы списка,
  // нужно запомнить, был ли открыт нужный
  const isClosed = !target.is(':visible');

  //закрыть все открытие элементы списка
  $('.slide_menu').slideUp();
  // Если нужный элемент был закрыт, значит надо его открыть
  if(isClosed) target.slideDown();
  // else ничего делать не надо, всё уже закрыто.
});
```